# Convert PDF of different dimension of table to XML in java:APACHE FO

Tags: java

I have a pdf file which I need to convert it into XML file using Java.In my pdf file, there are different tables of different dimesions.Please suggest the approach.

Please note, the input pdf file was generated from xml using Apache FO and now I again I need to convert back to xml.

Comment: Can you explain **why** you want to do that? It might be theoretically possible, but it is hardly practical. Still, the theoretical approach would be to parse the PDF into an object model and implement an XML formatter for said model.
If your PDF was generated using Apache FOP, how about simply keeping/re-using the corresponding XML and XSLT files?

Comment: I have a requirement in my project.I got a pdf file which was generted using Apache FOP,and now I need to read the parametee values from the tables present in pdf which again I need to convert into xml.Please help me with sample approach.

Comment: I still think you are going about this the wrong way, but if you are still determined to parse PDF files have a look at [iText RUPS](http://github.com/itext/rups/). RUPS includes a PDF object model viewer which implies support for parsing PDF into an object model first. Moreover, [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) is probably able to parse PDF files as well (never used it myself).